# Why am I still getting a "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I see the component in react dev tools and each of the Summaries has a unique key on it. But the warning won't go away.

```
const summaryData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      box: "one",
      sprite: "html5",   
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      box: "two",
      sprite: "envelope",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      box: "three",
      sprite: "wordpress",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      box: "four",
      sprite: "tongue",
    },
  ];
```

```
{summaryData.map((summary) => (
            <Summaries
              key={`box${summary.id}`}
              box={summary.box}
              sprite={summary.sprite}
            />
          ))}
```

Comment: Maybe because you are still using a sequential ID (similar to an actual index)? Why don't you use `box` instead of `id`?

Comment: Or even better, mix both `id` and `box` prop as component key: ```key={`${summary.id}_${summary.box}`}```

Comment: I tried `key={summary.box}` and `key={`${summary.id}_${summary.box}`}` and neither worked.

Comment: Maybe it's not that list which causes the warning

Comment: Seems Konrad is correct. Something else was interfering and causing the warning. Now I have a different problem of that thing not working anymore now.

Comment: I'm voting to close as not reproducible because the problem seems to be within code that was not provided.  `Summaries` creates multiple elements as evidenced by this [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77130206/1563833) which no external answerer could have confirmed.  Kudos to Konrad for intuiting it, though, which shows great experience and wisdom.  But the asker has not debugged the problem correctly.  I'm prepared to blame React for making it difficult to diagnose, but still...not a great question since the critical sub-arrays within the data were culled making it not reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the unique key with the index value as below instead. I always find this approach easier to read and you are far less likely to run into any errors also.

```
    summaryData.map((summary, index) => (
        <Summaries
            key={index}
            box={summary.box}
            sprite={summary.sprite}
        />
    ))}
```

Comment: this is really the right answer, using the iterator ensures the key is always unique within the iteration and a bad id / piece of data can't cause errors.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that it really wasn't a key problem but a problem with how I did my data in my array. Thanks Konrad.

The problem now is I need to pass html with props and render in Summaries.

If I leave it as is then the html renders but I get the key warning. If I wrap the html inside quotes then it won't render correctly and I see code in Summaries.

```
const summaryData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      box: "one",
      sprite: ["html5", <br class='hide' />],   
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      box: "two",
      sprite: "envelope",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      box: "three",
      sprite: "wordpress",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      box: "four",
      sprite: "tongue",
    },
  ];
```

Comment: on he key subject just use the array index that others have mentioned there is rarely a real need to anything more than that, then you'll never have to debug that if your data isn't right. for rendering the html, react has a prop called dangerouslySetInnerHTML which you can attach to any element and use to render html fragment inside.

Answer (score -1):

You could always create a composite key by concatenating multiple field values or hashing the object.

```js
const { StrictMode, useEffect, useState } = React;

const fetchSummaryData = () => Promise.resolve([
  { id: 1, box: "one", sprite: "html5" },
  { id: 2, box: "two", sprite: "envelope" },
  { id: 3, box: "three", sprite: "wordpress" },
  { id: 4, box: "four", sprite: "tongue" },
]);

const BoxSummary = ({ id, box, sprite }) => (<div>{sprite}</div>);

const App = () => {
  const [summaryData, setSummaryData] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchSummaryData().then(setSummaryData);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {summaryData.map(({ id, box, sprite }, _index) => (
        <BoxSummary
          key={box + id /* supply a composite key */}
          id={id}
          box={box}
          sprite={sprite}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
  .render((
    <StrictMode>
      <App />
    </StrictMode>
  ));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: @NikkiPantony it's not extra code. It is a runnable snippet with the minimal code needed to get it to run. The state should be fetched upon mounting.